# Find Value Type of a JSONValue (TJSONArray or TJSONObject)

Tags: arrays, json, delphi, object, delphi-xe8

I would like to do this with the standard Library in Delphi XE8

```
if Assigned(JSONValue) then
    case JSONValue.ValueType of
      jsArray  : ProcessArrayResponse(JSONValue as TJSONArray);
      jsObject : ProcessObjectResponse(JSONValue as TJSONObject);
    end;
end;
```

(this sample come from https://github.com/deltics/delphi.libs/wiki/JSON but using Deltics.JSON library).

Does Anyone know how to do it with standard library ?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `is` operator:

```
if Assigned(JSONValue) then
begin
  if JSONValue is TJSONArray then
    ProcessArrayResponse(TJSONArray(JSONValue))
  else if JSONValue is TJSONObject then
    ProcessObjectResponse(TJSONObject(JSONValue));
end;
```

If you want to use a `case` statement then you will have to create your own lookup:

```
type
  JsonValueType = (jsArray, jsObject, ...);

function GetJsonValueType(JSONValue: TJSONValue): JsonValueType;
begin
  if JSONValue is TJSONArray then Exit(jsArray);
  if JSONValue is TJSONObjct then Exit(jsObject);
  ...
end;

...

if Assigned(JSONValue) then
begin
  case GetJsonValueType(JSONValue) of
    jsArray  : ProcessArrayResponse(TJSONArray(JSONValue));
    jsObject : ProcessObjectResponse(TJSONObject(JSONValue));
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```
type
  JsonValueType = (jsArray, jsObject, ...);

var
  JsonValueTypes: TDictionary<String, JsonValueType>;

...

if Assigned(JSONValue) then
begin
  case JsonValueTypes[JSONValue.ClassName] of
    jsArray  : ProcessArrayResponse(TJSONArray(JSONValue));
    jsObject : ProcessObjectResponse(TJSONObject(JSONValue));
  end;
end;

...

initialization
  JsonValueTypes := TDictionary<String, JsonValueType>.Create;
  JsonValueTypes.Add('TSONArray', jsArray);
  JsonValueTypes.Add('TSONObject', jsObject);
  ...
finalization
  JsonValueTypes.Free;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `is` operator to distinguish between the possible value types. So,

```
var
  obj: TJSONObject;
  arr: TJSONArray;
....
if JSONValue is TJSONObject then
  obj := TJSONObject(JSONValue)
else if JSONValue is TJSONArray then
  arr := TJSONArray(JSONValue)
else
  // other possible types are TJSONNumber, TJSONString, TJSONTrue, TJSONFalse, TJSONNull
```

Answer (score 0):

I make some tests and found this way (seems to work i'm testing it)

```
FData : TJSONArray;

...

if JSONValue is TJSONObject then
   FData := TJSONArray(JSONValue as TJSONObject)
else if JSONValue is TJSONArray then
   FData := JSONValue as TJSONArray
else if JSONValue is TJSONString then
   FData := nil;
```

Comment: `TJSONArray(JSONValue as TJSONObject)` is doomed to failure. A value cannot be both an object and an array.

Comment: I tested it with 2 differents kind of data.. it work properly ! (it will create an array with only one record in it)

Comment: How can a class be both `TJSONObject` and `TJSONArray`? They are in different branches of the inheritance structure. Your cast is bogus.

Comment: case 1 : {"D":{"KEY1":"1"}}

Comment: case 2 : {"D":[{"KEY1":"1"},{"KEY1":"2"}]}

Comment: When i map case 1 as an array it provide me to use same procedure to extract the data (as an array in every case). This work

Comment: Well, if you know best, I'm not going to argue with you. One wonders why you ask in the first place.

Comment: Of course David i know you are better programmer than me. While i was waiting answers here, i perform a lot's of test and find this way to work properly. i'm just learning by doing. And maybe i'm not enough care about the "theorical part" because sometimes things should not work in theory but in real, it work ! I'm not telling it's the best way to do, but in my case it fullfill my needs. (for info i stop programmind Delphi with the end of Delphi 7, i just restart programming now since Delphi XE7 it's a Quantic Gap for me, need to learn a lot)

Comment: It doesn't work. If you would like me to help you understand why not, I will gladly do so.

Comment: Well, it's as I already said. A value cannot be both an object and an array. Your code violates that. Once you have a `TJSONObject` it simply cannot also be a `TJSONArray`. If you had used a checked cast, `as`, you'd have discovered that at runtime.

Comment: I didn't get any error. I think a TJSONArray can contain a TJSONObject ? maybe when i wrote : TJSONArray(JSONValue as TJSONObject) it's like my JSON of case 1 becoming something like this ? "D":[{"KEY1":"1"}]} maybe ? i'm not able to explain why it work ! and maybe i do in the wrong way. do you have another way ?

Comment: OK, if you are sure. I give up.

Comment: Or maybe the TJSONArray casting internal procedure have a function to detect if what i'm trying to cast is an object then maybe it doing this TJSONArray.Add(JSONObject) ? probably ? because i'm agree with you a JSONObject is Not and JSONArray ! this i'm fully agree with you. Thx for your help

Comment: I'm not going to continue arguing with you. Your code is just wrong. I've explained why. I don't want to force you to listen to me.

Comment: What is your solution ? (constraint : The treatment i do after this, need to work with TJSONArray)

Comment: An object is not an array. Your constraint cannot be met.

Comment: What David is trying to explain is that `FData := TJSONArray(JSONValue as TJSONObject)` is wrong. If it works in this case is by sheer luck.

Comment: After David explained me, i understand that it's not the proper way to do it. And i admit i get the "beginer's lucky time" to try that kind of code by searching desperately a solution... Thank you for your help.